# How do I ignore a particular gcc warning that's [enabled by default]?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, warnings, pragma

I have the following program that prints green text to the terminal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//returns a colored string for terminal output streams
std::string colorize_forground(std::string const& message, int const& background) {
    return std::string("\e[38;5;" + std::to_string(background) + "m" + message + "\x1b[0m");
}

int main() {
    std::cout << colorize_forground("hello world in green", 106) << '\n';
}
```

However, when I compile the program with the following warning flag,

> g++ -std=c++1y **-pedantic** -o main prob.cpp

I get this warning message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::string colorize_forground(const string&, const int&)’:
main.cpp:6:21: warning: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e' [enabled by default]
  return std::string("\e[38;5;" + std::to_string(background) + "m" + message + "\x1b[0m");
```

**How do I continue using -pedantic, but ignore the warning for this particular function?**

I've been trying to use [gcc's Diagnostic Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to ignore this escape sequence warning.
I wrapped the function the following way, but it still elicits a warning.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
std::string colorize_forground(std::string const& message, int const& background) {
    return std::string("\e[38;5;" + std::to_string(background) + "m" + message + "\x1b[0m");
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: This does not solve the general problem, but you can use `\x1b` in your specific case instead of `\e`, like you're already doing the second time you need it.

Answer (score 2):

All available flags and their meanings can be seen at:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Change the link to the gcc version of your choice. In general, flags that start with `-Wno` are the ones that will disable warnings that would otherwise be enabled.

> How do I continue using -pedantic, but ignore the warning for this particular function?

The `-pedandic` flag will show all errors and warnings controlled by this
flag. Since you are concerned with a warning, you might consider using the `-pedantic-errors`, which will only produce the errors, and not the warnings. This is not *exactly* what you asked for, but might suffice.

There is also this flag which may or may not apply to you: `-Wno-pedantic-ms-format` (MinGW targets only)

Comment: Why link to the manual for GCC 4.4, which is ancient and doesn't show all the options for the OP's version?

Comment: @JonathanWakely That link is what I had handy. As I said though: "**Change the link to the gcc version of your choice.**" Also, what is the OP's version? I don't see that information mentioned anywhere.

Comment: It supports `-std=c++1y` so must be at least 4.8.0